# In between multiple tabs, how to use Vimperator to open a tab right after the current one

Tags: firefox, vimperator, browser-tabs

My tabs:

[1] [2] [3] [4] [**5**] [6] [7] [8] [9]

### Scenario

I am working on the **5th** tab on Firefox and looking for a way to open a tab between **5th** and **6th** and not after **9th** which would be done by <kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd>

I do lots of research and while its going I tend to keep multiple (numinous) tabs open and sometimes I tend to keep the related ones close to each-other temporarily. *In-case you were wondering why*.

Comment: Between 5th and 6th: in other words to the right of the 5th. The way you put it, it *almost* makes it sound like you want to split a tab by the middle. But I got the idea. As a fellow *tab addict* (that's an official term used by Mozilla) I can understand why you would want this. I'm afraid I don't know of a way to achieve this. Well, not easily anyway.

Comment: When you create a new tab, it will open at the end of the tab strip. But when you open a link in a new tab, it will open to the right of the current tab. I understand this is what you want. Perhaps if we were to examine the source code for that function (Firefox is open source after all), we might be able to create an extension that would call that function, and bind it to a keyboard shortcut. Perhaps something like Ctrl+Alt+T?

Comment: But that would of course take a lot of time and effort. It is probably better to have a look at what extensions and advanced tweaks and options already exist that we can use. I see you're using one called Vimperator. I am not familiar with that. Is this where you use T and O keys? Is that without Ctrl?

Comment: You could try Tab Groups which is built into Firefox. You invoke it with Ctrl+Shift+E. There, you can group related tabs. Also, it is possible to pin tabs. That might be useful as well. It makes them collapse so that only the favicon is visible and moves them to the left-most part of the tab strip.

Comment: @sammyg I'm a Firefox addict but to be frank didn't know about *tab addict*. I'm aware of Firefox features and yes the keys I've mentioned are Vimperator keys and work on their own. And no, I don't want to split a tab :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: General

The following code defines a command to open an URL in a tab next to the current tab. You can place it in your `.vimperatorrc` file or save it as a separate file and source it in `.vimperatorrc`.

```
" Defines commands to open new tab to right of current tab

" Example keybinding: xt
nmap xt :newtabright<SPACE>

command! newtabright -nargs=1 -description "Open new tab to right of current tab" :js newTabRight("<args>");

:js <<EOF
function newTabRight(args) {
    var origOrd = gBrowser.selectedTab._tPos;
    var numTabs = tabs.count;
    liberator.open(args, liberator.NEW_TAB)
    var newTab = tabs.getTab();
    tabs.move(newTab, origOrd+1);
}
EOF
```

I've uploaded this code as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/troyp/2c0be7bbb646b3387909), so you can download it and save it in your `.vimperator` directory if you like. Then you can source it from your rc file with

```
:source ~/.vimperator/newtabright.vimperator
```

There's also a [Pentadactyl version](https://gist.github.com/troyp/70faaec7d97f67477e86).

To open an URL in a tab to the right, just enter the following at the Vimperator command line:

```
newtabright www.example.com
```

...or, using the example keybinding, type:
<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>`www.example.com`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

## Method 2: requires about.config setting browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent

Assuming you have the `about.config` setting `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent` set to `true`, you can use a simpler method (which can even - conditionally - be used without Vimperator/Pentadactyl).

Create a new bookmarklet. Name it whatever (eg. "new tab to right"), and in the `location` field, enter the following:

```
javascript:window.open('%s');void(0);
```

In the `keyword` field, enter a convenient keyword, eg. `r`.

This is a combination or a bookmarklet and a "search" bookmark (although we're not using it to search). You can use it either from FF's location bar, or from Vimperator's open prompt. Simply type the keyword followed by the URL. So using Vimperator's keybindings, to open example.com, we'd just type:
<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>`example.com`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### With the Firefox location bar (vanilla FF)...

We can use the bookmarklet with the FF location bar as well. Using the standard FF key binding, we'd open `example.com` by typing:
<kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>`example.com`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

...which is actually marginally quicker than the Vimperator command line.

However, using this method from the location bar won't work if you have FF's popup-blocker active (**menu ▷ Preferences ▷ Content ▷ Pop-ups**). This is because javascript scheme URLs entered at the location bar (or from a bookmarklet) are treated the same as javascript executed by a web page, whereas Vimperator's command line `:javascript` command executes the code with it's extension privileges.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact same behavior as `:tabopen`, use this:

```
nnoremap    <A-[>       :tabopenleft<SPACE>
nnoremap    <A-]>       :tabopenright<SPACE>

:js <<EOF
commands.addUserCommand
    ( ["tabopenright", "tabnewright"]
    , "Open one or more URLs in a new tab to the right"
    , function (args)
        { var origOrd = gBrowser.selectedTab._tPos;
          commands.get("tabopen").action(args);
          var newTab = tabs.getTab();
          tabs.move(newTab, origOrd + 1);
        }
    , { bang        : commands.get("tabopen").bang
      , completer   : commands.get("tabopen").completer
      , literal     : commands.get("tabopen").literal
      , privateData : commands.get("tabopen").privateData
      }
    , true
    );
commands.addUserCommand
    ( ["tabopenleft", "tabnewleft"]
    , "Open one or more URLs in a new tab to the left"
    , function (args)
        { var origOrd = gBrowser.selectedTab._tPos;
          commands.get("tabopen").action(args);
          var newTab = tabs.getTab();
          tabs.move(newTab, origOrd + 0);
        }
    , { bang        : commands.get("tabopen").bang
      , completer   : commands.get("tabopen").completer
      , literal     : commands.get("tabopen").literal
      , privateData : commands.get("tabopen").privateData
      }
    , true
    );
EOF
```

This answer was created in part using [pyrocrasty's 1st method](https://superuser.com/a/947850/305146) and using [vimperator's source](https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs).