# Vimperator tabopen not a vimperator command

Tags: firefox, vimperator

For some reason Firefox's vimperator :tabopen command suddenly doesn't work. :open still works. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update #2: fix released

- reinstall Vimperator

### Update: fix done

Fix was done and contributed to Vimperator, new version was built with it, but it needs Mozilla's verification before publishing so it will take time.

If you wish to have it, follow [this issue comment](https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/568#issuecomment-275891186). I have not done that myself yet, so will not republish under my name (yet).

### Reason why it doesn't work

Firefox changed how their rendering engine treats JS and Vimperator needs to adjust (e.g. legacy generator functions - those with `yield` - are now dropped).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/Firefox_JavaScript_changelog#Firefox_51

### Tab opening workaround

1. Open your `.vimperatorrc` file (GNU/Linux: `/home/username/.vimperatorrc`)
2. Add this (strange format due to - I think - << resulting in SO thinking I'm trying to do nasty work here and NOT displaying part of the code):

`" Example keybinding: xt`

`nmap xt :extraTab<SPACE>`

`command! extraTab -nargs=1 -description "Open an extra tab" :js extraTab("<args>");`

`:js <<EOF`

`function extraTab(args) {`

`liberator.open(args, liberator.NEW_TAB)`

`}`

`EOF`

### Real solution

Needs to make `tabs` defined again, as now it ain't thus making it hard to do lots of tab-related things.

It requires Vimperator code re-work and an update, so go and upvote (don't comment, just upvote original post) an issue:

https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/568

Answer (score 3):

It's broken for many people. If you can't wait for the fix to be released, there is a workaround method available (that works for me at least) https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/568#issuecomment-275755483

Comment: Please include the diff for an even better answer so in case of a rotting link or deleted comment it's still useful.

Answer (score 2):

I mapped `t` to `Control+t + open` in .vimperatorrc like so:

> `nnoremap t <C-t> o` 
>   `nnoremap T y <C-t> o <C-v>`

This mimics the old tabopen command.

You can also do this for the other commands like Jack Doe shows.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to downgrade Firefox back to 50.1.*

**EDIT:**
Vimperator is working in version **54.0.1**

Just tried out `qutebrowser` which is a browser written for vim users. It looks awesome but it doesn't have dev tools (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm now using `cVim` in Chrome and I'm pretty satisfied with it, recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the file ".vimperatorrc" or "_vimperatorrc":

`nnoremap t <C-t>`

So when you press "t", rather than using ":tabopen " it opens a new tab in Firefox and lets you type in the url bar.

I'm a Windows user so I created my "_vimperatorrc" file in the folder titled my name (the same folder which has My Documents in it).

PS: If you have `set gui=nonavigation` in your vimperatorrc, this will not work, you instead use

`nnoremap t <C-t>:open` with a space after `open`.

Also, for me "r" also stopped refreshing, and "d" also stopped closing tabs, so the lines below fixed it.

`nnoremap r <C-r>`

`nnoremap d <C-w>`

Answer (score 0):

Define a command like `newtabright` to use it like this:

```
newtabright www.example.com
```

Take a look at [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/935231/in-between-multiple-tabs-how-to-use-vimperator-to-open-a-tab-right-after-the-cu) answer on how to do this.

Comment: unfortunately still not a vimperator command

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and looks like it is a FF51.0 thingie,
so made a bug report:
https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/671

HTH

Comment: Downvoted as this newly-created issue is a duplicate. Read https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/568 instead for live updates.

Answer (score 0):

LIttle Ancient Forest Kami pretty much had the right workaround but was missing a few lines (since stack overflow seems to remove it since its a command). With this in your .vimperatorrc you can open new tabs with the command :extraTab (url)

" Example keybinding: xt
nmap xt :extraTab

command! extraTab -nargs=1 -description "Open an extra tab" :js extraTab("");

:js << EOF

function extraTab(args) {
    liberator.open(args, liberator.NEW_TAB)
}
EOF

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround in Windows, Firefox version 51.0.1.

In _vimperatorrc:

`nnoremap t <C-t> <ESC> o`

This will open a new tab, then switches back to normal mode to run :open command.